# How to access vue data instance inside nested function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm playing around something like this

```
myFunc(){
   new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    setTimeout(function(){
      //
      resolve();
     },1000)
    })
   .then(function(){
      this.a = 10;
    });
   console.log(this.a)
}
```

I want to update the vue data property `a` inside a nested function. What's wrong here ? Note that I cann't use arrow function here for some reason.

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/bkvcy6j2/

Comment: `.then(() => {this.a = 10;});` or `.then(function(){this.a = 10;}.bind(this));` but in both cases the Promise is async so this.a wont be updated before you console log it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because `this` in `then` is no the `vue.$el`. The best way would be do use Arrow Fn.

```
myFunc() {
  new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      //
      resolve();
     },1000)
   })
  .then(() => {
    this.a = 10;
    console.log(self.a) // here logs 10
  });
  console.log(this.a) // here logs null
}
```

If you can't use Arrow Fn assign `this` to `variable`:

```
myFunc() {
  const self = this
  new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    setTimeout(function(){
      //
      resolve();
     },1000)
   })
  .then(function(){
    self.a = 10;
  });
  console.log(self.a)
}
```

Comment: sorry but `const self = this` grinds my gears

Comment: @LawrenceCherone OK, but it works, it solf the problem, so why minus? This is unfair man. You give a negatife feadback but you didn't give any solution yourself.

Comment: it's not working @AdamOrlov. Can you play it here : https://jsfiddle.net/bkvcy6j2/2/ ?

Comment: It does but, the `console.log` is before `then` so it shows the old `value`. Try `console.log` in `then`. Look: https://jsfiddle.net/khrx2g87/#&togetherjs=9whTbJ8aTi